# Javascript Admin, User - setAccess Level OOP

Tags: javascript, oop

I have such a problem.
I created three classes, User, Admin and App.

The App class creates new users with different access levels. Admin can change passwords, email and access level of other users.
Currently, the Admin can change the above options himself.

e.g. const admin = New Admin (...)
admin.setPassword (...)

I want to use the App class and be able to creating an Admin, User and the possibility that the created admin can change the password, an email, to another User.

```
`use strict`
```

```
class Validator {
    static isStrings(...value) {
        value.forEach(el => {
            if (typeof el !== "string") {
                throw new Error("it is not a string value")
            }
            if (el.length === 0) {
                throw new Error("Provide a string value")
            }
        });
    }
    static checkEmail(email) {
        const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-](.{7,32})+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9].{1,3})*$/g
        if (!regex.test(email)) {
            throw new Error(`Email address has a wrong format! Correct format is 8-32 characters, at least one capital letter, one number and one special character `);
        }
    }

    static checkPassword(password) {
        const regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!#$%^&*()<>?])+.{9,32}$/g
        if (!regex.test(password)) {
            throw new Error(`Invalid password. Password must have from 8 to 32 characters, includes at least one capital letter, one number and one special character  `);
        }
    }
    static checkGender(gender) {
        if (!["male", "female"].includes(gender.toString().toLowerCase())) {
            throw new Error("Gender, male or female only")
        }
    }

    // - data (nieważne jaka wejdzie) do konstruktora musi wejść w formacie MM/DD/YYYY

    static checkDate(value) {
        const regex = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/g
        const correctDate = regex.test(value)
        if (!correctDate) {
            throw new Error("Incorrect date format. Correct one is MM/DD/YYYY")
        }
    }

    static checkInputAccessLevel = (accLevel) => {
        if (!["admin", "user"].includes(accLevel.toString().toLowerCase())) {
            throw new Error(`Access level is not an "admin" or "user"`)
        }
    }

}
class User {
    constructor(name, secondName, dateOfBirth, password, gender, emailAddress) {
        Validator.isStrings(name, secondName)
        // Validator.checkInputAccessLevel(accessLevel)
        Validator.checkPassword(password)
        Validator.checkGender(gender)
        Validator.checkEmail(emailAddress)
        Validator.checkDate(dateOfBirth)

        this.name = name
        this.secondName = secondName
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
        this.password = password
        this.gender = gender
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress
        this.accessLevel = "user"
    }
    changeName = (value) => {
        this.name = value
    }
    changeSecondName = (value) => {
        this.secondName = value
    }
    changeDateOfBirth = (value) => {
        this.dateOfBirth = value
    }
    changeGender = (value) => {
        this.gender = value
    }
}



class Admin {
    constructor(name, secondName, dateOfBirth, password, gender, emailAddress) {
        Validator.isStrings(name, secondName)
        // Validator.checkInputAccessLevel(accessLevel)
        Validator.checkPassword(password)
        Validator.checkGender(gender)
        Validator.checkEmail(emailAddress)
        Validator.checkDate(dateOfBirth)

        this.name = name
        this.secondName = secondName
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
        this.password = password
        this.gender = gender
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress
        this.accessLevel = "admin"
    }

    setPassword = (newPassword) => {
        Validator.checkPassword(newPassword)
        this.password = newPassword
    }
    setEmail = (newEmail) => {
        Validator.checkEmail(newEmail)
        this.emailAddress = newEmail

    }
    setAccessLevel = (level) => {
        Validator.checkInputAccessLevel(level)
        this.accessLevel = level
    }

}

class App {
    constructor() {
        this.allUsers = []
    }
    createAdmin = (name, secondName, dateOfBirth, password, gender, emailAddress) => {
        const admin = new Admin(name, secondName, dateOfBirth, password, gender, emailAddress)
        this.allUsers.push(admin)
        return admin
    }
    createUser = (name, secondName, dateOfBirth, password, gender, emailAddress) => {
        const user = new User(name, secondName, dateOfBirth, password, gender, emailAddress)
        this.allUsers.push(user)
        return user
    }
    showAllUsers = () => {
        return this.allUsers
    }
}


// const userAdmin = new Admin("John", "Smith", "27/02/1969", "Password!@#1!", "male", "johnSmith1M!@gmail.com")
// const userUser = new User("Andy", "Hopkins", "07/02/1999", "AndyHopkons!@#1!", "male", "andyHopkons!@#1A@gamil.com")

// console.log(userAdmin)
// console.log(userUser)


const app = new App
app.createAdmin("John", "Smith", "27/02/1969", "Password!@#1!", "male", "johnSmith1M!@gmail.com")
app.createUser("Andy", "Hopkins", "07/02/1999", "AndyHopkons!@#1!", "male", "andyHopkons!@#1A@gmail.com")

console.log(app.showAllUsers())
```